# Browsers, do they treat a random query string as a different file?

Tags: php, performance, url, query-string

If I set a far future expire header for this file (take note of the query string):

```
/css/getCSS.php?v=1284532156.css
```

Will it treat the entire URL (including the query string) as a single file and respect the expire deceleration, but request the next version of the file...

```
/css/getCSS.php?v=1284599999.css
```

...from the server as it won't have it in cache yet?

I'm not in a position where I can use `.htaccess` to mask / rewrite a file from `/css/v156845156.css` to `/css/getCSS.php?v=v156845156.css` and unsure whether including the unique file name in the query string will be sufficient to make the browser behave like any other, differently named files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and its a common way to work around cache control. If you use it the other way around that is.

Comment: Thanks for your super quick answer, but what do you mean by other way around?

Comment: I think he means `/css/mycssfile.css?version=1234` where the `version` argument is just there to defeat cache (it's not used at all)...